# Proper MVVM implementation of dynamically generated usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

My scenario: I have a usercontrol consisting of a comboBox, and a TextBox. The comboBox should hold numbers contained in an ObservableCollection.

The task: The numbers in the ObservableCollection represent paths to book-chapters; therefore each chapter is unique. Meaning: if I have chapters 1 - 5, then the first userControl combo should show all chapters 1-5 (whereas one of them is selected randomly), the second userControl combo contains all chapters, but not the one selected in the previous combo, and so on. The textBox is for annotations for the chapters.

What I achieved so far: I have currently no model; just a main viewModel (ItemsViewModel in my case), and a viewModel for my userControl (PathViewModel). Then there is the mainWindow view.

The problem: On my mainWindow I can create several dynamically created userControls. The userControl TextBox is currently bound to a text property, while the index of the comboBox is bound to another property. But I **don't** know: 
- how to gain access to the index, selected item/value of the specifically userControls
- how to react to a comboBox item/index change

Here is my code:
The userControl

```
<UserControl>  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ComboBox x:Name="combo" Margin="10" MinWidth="60" VerticalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableNumbers}" SelectedIndex="{Binding TheIndex}" />
    <TextBox Margin="10" MinWidth="120" Text="{Binding TheText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

The MainWindow

```
<Window>...<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ItemsViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel x:Name="HostPanel">

        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PathViewModels}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:PathControl/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>

    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
    <Button Command="{Binding UCCreationCommand}" Content="Add User Control" Margin="10"/>
    <Button Command="{Binding UCDeletionCommand}" CommandParameter="" Content="Delete User Control" Margin="10"/>
    <Button Command="{Binding ReadoutCommand}" Content="Show ITEMS" Margin="10"/>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid></Window>
```

My main ViewModel (called ItemsViewModel)

```
public class ItemsViewModel : NotifyPropertyChangedBase    
{private int _aNumber;
 public int ANumber
{
get { return _aNumber; }
set { _aNumber = value;
OnPropertyChanged(ref _aNumber, value);
}
 }
 public ObservableCollection<PathViewModel> PathViewModels { get; set; } = new 
ObservableCollection<PathViewModel>();

    public ObservableCollection<int> AllNumbers { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<int>();

    public ItemsViewModel()
    {
        UCCreationCommand = new CommandDelegateBase(UCCreationExecute, UCCreationCanExecute);
        UCDeletionCommand = new CommandDelegateBase(UCDeletionExecute, UCDeletionCanExecute);
        ReadoutCommand = new CommandDelegateBase(ReadoutExecute, ReadoutCanExecute);

        AllNumbers.Add(1);
        AllNumbers.Add(2);
        AllNumbers.Add(3);
        AllNumbers.Add(4);
        AllNumbers.Add(5);
    }

    private bool ReadoutCanExecute(object paramerter)
    {
        if (PathViewModels.Count > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void ReadoutExecute(object parameter)
    {
        //just for testing
    }

    public ICommand UCCreationCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand UCDeletionCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand ReadoutCommand { get; set; }


    private bool UCCreationCanExecute(object paramerter)
    {
        if (PathViewModels.Count < 8)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void UCCreationExecute(object parameter)
    {
        PathViewModel p = new PathViewModel();

        foreach (int i in AllNumbers)
        {
            p.AvailableNumbers.Add(i);
        }

        int rndIndex = 0;

        Random rnd = new Random();

        //creates a random chapter index
        rndIndex = rnd.Next(0, p.AvailableNumbers.Count);

        //just explicit for debugging reasons
        p.TheIndex = rndIndex;
```

AllNumbers.RemoveAt(rndIndex);

```
        PathViewModels.Add(p);
    }

    private bool UCDeletionCanExecute(object paramerter)
    {
        if (PathViewModels.Count != 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }

    private void UCDeletionExecute(object parameter)
    {
        PathViewModel p = new PathViewModel();
        int delIndex = PathViewModels.Count - 1;

        p = PathViewModels[delIndex];

        AllNumbers.Add((int)p.TheValue+1);


        PathViewModels.Remove(p);
    }     

}
```

And finally my UserControl ViewModel:

```
public class PathViewModel : NotifyPropertyChangedBase
{

    public ObservableCollection<int> AvailableNumbers { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<int>();

    private int _theIndex;

    public int TheIndex
    {
        get { return _theIndex; }
        set
        {
            _theIndex = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(ref _theIndex, value);
        }
    }

    private int _theValue;

    public int TheValue
    {
        get { return _theValue; }
        set
        {
            _theValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(ref _theValue, value);
        }
    }

    private string _theText;

    public string TheText
    {
        get { return _theText; }
        set
        {
            _theText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(ref _theText, value);
        }
    }

    public PathViewModel()
    {

    }       

}
```

Any hints on how to go on from here would be highly appreaciated.

Comment: so the key is each `usercontrol` dynamically created should have a `ViewModel` created. so if you have an `event` in `combobox` it will trigger in your `viewModel`. all depends how you are dynamically creating `usercontrols`

Comment: <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:ViewModelName}">
                <view:ViewName />
    </DataTemplate>
you have to create a DataTemplate like above in the resource and you can generate your ViewModels in a collection which will create your `UserControls`
Then you will have the control on all viewModels in the collection.

Comment: Maybe your `PathViewModel` could store the selected values and act on it. So when you select a chapter `PathViewModel` stores that decision and then you create one which would have stored decision. Selected Index would be then complex as it would have to consider previous choices. How do you disable already chosen chapters?

Comment: Albin, so I'm not totally sure: the Data-Template is on the userControl.xaml? If so, how do the events of the code behind interact with my viewModel? Or is the viewModel-collection also part of the userControl-viewModel?

Comment: DataTemplate should be in the parent View's resource or App.xaml or resource dictionary.
ViewModel collection should be in your parent ViewModel.